# Find out the factors of this expression by long division.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two factors of the expression $x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x - 6$ are $ (x+1) $ and $ (x - 3)$ .

Find the other two factors by long division.

Comment: Done.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Yup, how to do long division?

Comment: Do we really need to do long division?

Comment: yeah, this is the question. :/ I did it by other way, I found $(x-2)$ and $(x+1)$. But they said to do it by long division. :(

Comment: Don't you know how long term division works, or what's the problem with this task?

Comment: No, it is too long and I get confused!

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x -6 \equiv (x^2-2x-3)(x^2-3x+2)$. The method is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|ccccc}
& & &x^2 & -3x & +2 \\
\hline x^2 & -2x & -3 & x^4 & -5x^3 & +5x^2 & 5x & -6 \\
&  &  & x^4 & -2x^3 & -3x^2 &  \downarrow&  \downarrow\\
\hline &  &  &  & -3x^3 & +8x^2 & 5x &  \downarrow\\ 
&  &  &  & -3x^3 & +6x^2 & 9x &  \downarrow\\
\hline &  &  &  &  & +2x^2 & -4x & -6 \\
&  &  &  &  & +2x^2 & -4x & -6 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Kiara You're welcome. I'm just sorry that you didn't think it was the most useful answer.

Comment: Oh no, why are you thinking like that? Of course it is useful to me! You shouldn't be sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward: Divide your polynomial by $(x + 1)(x - 3) = x^2 -2x -3$. Long division of a polynomial by another polynomial works just like long-division of numbers works.

Review the process of [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and study the examples.

Then give it a try with your polynomials.

Comment: You have a remarkable answer's style. I like it

Answer (score 1):

With the given polynomial $x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x - 6$, long division by $x+1$ and $x-3$ is accomplished in much the same way as when using long division between numbers.  Taking the comment-suggested divisor as $x^2-2x-3$, we have:

$$x^2-2x-3\mid x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x - 6$$

$$x^2(x^2-2x-3)=x^4-2x^3-3x^2$$

$$(x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x - 6)-(x^4-2x^3-3x^2)=-3x^3+8x^2+5x-6$$

$$-3x(x^2-2x-3)=-3x^3+6x^2+9x$$

$$(-3x^3+8x^2+5x-6)-(-3x^3+6x^2+9x)=2x^2-4x-6$$

and finally

$$2(x^2-2x-3)=2x^2-4x-6$$

So we have

$$x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x - 6 = (x^2-2x-3)(x^2-3x+2)=(x+1)(x-3)(x-1)(x-2)$$

Writing out the division symbol and how "pulling down" each successive term works isn't easy for me with MaxJAX, but the process should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confused on how to do long division, [here](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac01/fac01.html) is a good example which will make things easier for you.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray} (x^2\!-\!2x\!-\!3)(x^2\!-\!bx\!+\!c) &=& x^4\ -\color{#0a0}{\ 5}\,\ x^3\! +\! 5x^2\! +\! 5x\! \color{#c00}{-\! 6} \\
&=& x^4\!\! -\! (\color{#0a0}{b\!+\!2})x^3+\ \cdots\ \color{#c00}{-{3}c}\end{eqnarray}$ $\ \Rightarrow\ $ $\color{#0a0}{b=3},\,\ \color{#c00}{c=2}$

Alternatively, if the roots are $\,3,-1,r,s\,$ then, by Vieta, $\,\color{#0a0}5 = 3\!-\!1\!+\!r\!+\!s,\,\  \color{#c00}{{-}6}= 3(-1)rs,\,$ hence $\,\color{#0a0}{r\!+\!s = 3},\,\ \color{#c00}{rs = 2}\ $ thus $\, (x\!-\!r)(x\!-\!s) = x^2-(\color{#0a0}{r\!+\!s})x+\color{#c00}{rs} = x^2-\color{#0a0}3x+\color{#c00}2$

Comment: @Kiara: This one is the best for showing the shortcuts to bypassing what is an otherwise-tedious process, even if it doesn't demonstrate the long division portion.